# Codeigniter REST web service and jquery mobiles AJAX in PhoneGap

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, rest, cordova, jquery-mobile

I've made a REST web service where I extract a name and surname and then simply send back a message containing a message with the name and surname in the result.

Now inside PhoneGap I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
     <head>
      <title>PhoneGap</title>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximumscale=1"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.css"/>

    <script type="text/javascript"  src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="js/jquerym.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="js/myscript.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova-2.3.0.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div id ="page1" data-role="page">
        <div data-role ="header">
            <h1>Welcome to Page 1</h1>
        </div>
        <a href="#page2" data-transition="flip">Page2</a>
    </div>

    <div id ="page2" data-role="page">
        <div data-role ="header">
            <h1>Welcome to Page 2</h1>
        </div>

        <form>
            First name: <input type="text" name="name" id="username"><br>
            Last name: <input type="text" name="surname" id="usersurname"><br>
            <input type="submit" id ="submit" name="submit" value="GO TIME">
        </form>
        <a href="#page1" data-transition="flip">Page1</a>
    </div>

 </body>
</html>
```

When the user enters values into the form it then runs the following js:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow','#page2',
    function(){
                $('#submit').click(function() 
                {
                    var name = $("#username").val();
                    var surname = $("#usersurname").val();

                    alert(name + " " + surname);

                    $.post(
                        "http://localhost/rest/index.php/api/test/name/"+name+"/surname/"+surname+"/format/json", 
                        {'name':name,'surname':surname},
                        function(data)
                        {
                            alert(data.result);
                        },
                        "json");
                });         
              });
```

In my Codeigniter REST I have set the base url and have the following code:

```
<?php

require(APPPATH.'/libraries/REST_Controller.php');
class API extends REST_Controller
{
    function test_post()
    {
        $name = $this->post('name');
        $surname = $this->post('surname');
        $result = "This is working ".$name." ".$surname;
        $array = array('result' => $result);
        $this->response($array); 
    }

}
?>
```

Now when the user enters their info in the input boxes and then clicks the button the js script works fine because the 1st alert appears but for some reason it doesn't go to the codeigniter REST and return a result it simply just sends me back to page 1.

Comment: Your method `test_get` is expecting a GET request, not a POST request. Try changing your method to `test_post`?

Comment: Thanks for spotting that. Ive made the changes but still get the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've probably solved this issue now, but I thought I'd answer it for you as I just had a similar issue and stumbled upon this question.

Basically, you won't be able to access 
`http://localhost/rest/index.php/api/test/name` from your emulator as your XAMPP server is hosted on a different machine (the emulator is a virtual machine). By changing the URL of your request to `http://192.168.0.7/rest/index.php/api/test/name` for example, you can access the apache server hosted on your PC. You'll have to find out your local IP by opening a command prompt and typing `ipconfig`. You'll also need to ensure that your networks firewall allows incoming traffic from port 80.

Answer (score 1):

This is not going to work, you can't use localhost on a phonegap mobile app.

If you are testing this code on a mobile device your $.POST destination is not a:

```
http://localhost/rest/index.php/api/test/name
```

Your phone has a different IP adress then your PHP server.

Find your PHP server IP and replace localhost with it.

Comment: All I've done is made a codeigniter website and now using the phonegap I want to make an app but I want to call some of the codeigniter controller methods. I was told to use a REST webs service. I'm trying to do that but with no luck. What is the best way to being able to access my codeigniter controllers??

Comment: First are testing phonegap app inside a simulator or a real mobile phone?

Comment: Im making an android app using the simulator

Comment: Can you access and find an IP address of your PHP server? If not tell me which OS you are using for your PHP server.

Comment: I would guess your IP is a 10.0.2.2, replace localhost with it

Comment: Sorry I miss read your last message. Im running XAMPP on windows 8

Comment: @user1638809 - what Gajotres is trying to see is simple. Localhost means a server that is seen by your machine, and when you put your url as localhost/... your phone will not navigate to your machine. what you have to do is to make a virtual host or something like a network between your phone and your machine so you can test it. and modify your url according to your modifications.

Comment: Sorry guys I'm a proper noob but I really appreciate the help. What I mean by localhost is that its a virtual service on my hard drive. It's what I use to develop on my pc. So should I place the codeigniter files in a hosted site and work it from there?